# UIScrollView zoomScale inconsistent

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

Below code runs as expected the first time I pick an image from camera roll. Image is zoomed out propery to fit in scrollView. But when I run it again to repick an image and pick the same image again, it gets zoomed to 1.0 scale. Cannot figure out what I need to reset to make it work the same everytime. Any ideas?

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    picView.image = nil
    picView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
    picView.removeFromSuperview()
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    scrollView.addSubview(picView)

    scrollView.contentSize = image.size

    let scaleWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width / scrollView.contentSize.width //image.size.width
    let scaleHeight = scrollView.frame.size.height / scrollView.contentSize.height //image.size.height
    let minScale = min(scaleWidth, scaleHeight)
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = minScale
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.0
    scrollView.zoomScale = minScale
}
```

Comment: What does debugging tell you? Is the value of `minScale` coming out correctly?

Comment: yes, min scale value is always same & correct but my doubt is that scrollView contentSize is getting messed up somehow. That would affect the zoom even though zoomscale is correct?

Comment: Right, because that's how zooming works.

Comment: yes, but i cannot figure out, where contentSize is getting messed up (if it is) in the code, I provided.

Comment: You are setting the content size when the old zoom scale is still in place. Thus, you get the wrong results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you've already figured this out, but I'll just fill in what might be the missing piece of the puzzle. How does zooming actually work? As I say [in my book](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch20.html#_zooming):

> The scroll view zooms by applying a *scaling transform* to the scalable view... Moreover, the scroll view is concerned to make scrolling continue to work correctly; ... therefore, the scroll view automatically scales its own contentSize to match the current zoomScale.

So you need to remove that transform before you start playing with the content size. Thus it might be sufficient to reset the `zoomScale` to 1 up front, before you go swapping out the image view.

Even better, why not leave the image view there? You seem to be doing a lot of unnecessary work in your routine; why not think of this as a scroll view with an image view content view, where what gets swapped out is only the image?

Finally, why not use auto layout? That way, the image's size *automatically* becomes the image view's size, and the image view's size *automatically* becomes the scroll view's content size.

Comment: Great! Adding `scrollView.zoomScale = 1.0` at beginning solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks @matt I was doing the unnecessary steps on removing and adding imageView in beginning in hopes to solve the issue.